# Get elastic search java api query for distinct field and sorting

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 2.3 version in my java project. I want to execute the following sql query for elastic search -

```
select fileName from (select distinct fileName from explore_object_metadata order by original_size desc)where rownum <=10
```

For this I try -

```
 client.prepareSearch()
                    .setIndices()
                    .setTypes(getType())
                    .addSort(fieldSort("sourceSize").order(DESC))
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(ES_TIMEOUT_MS))
                    .setSize(10);
```

But it gives me 10 result in descending order with repeated fileName multiple times. What can I do to get top 10 records with unique filename and sorted in descending order by their size in elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sense query to get the above query is -

```
{ 

  "aggs": {
    "id1_count": {
      "terms": { "field": "empname" ,
      "order": {
          "Max_Marks": "desc"
        }
      },

      "aggs": {
        "Max_Marks": {
          "max": {
            "field": "marks"
          }
        },
        "min_marks":{
            "min":{
                "field":"marks"
            }
        }
      }
```